# Ajax script only returns results sometimes?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a script running on xampp and when I run this script with alert call in it the file executes but when I run it without alerts it just sits there and doesnt return anything. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

var xhr;

function getPlants(xhr){
        try {
            xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }catch(microsoft){
            try{
                xhr=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }catch(othermicrosoft){
                    try{
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }catch(failed){
                        xhr=false;
                        alert("ajax not supported");
                    }
                }
        }

```
xhr.onreadystatechange=state_change;    
xhr.open("GET","db_interactions.php",true);     
xhr.send(null);
    alert("sent");


function state_change() {
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
        alert("all systems go");
        return xhr.responseText;
    }
```

}

Comment: @Daquan -- if you remove and replace the alerts one by one, which one does it stop working on?

Answer (score 0):

I would **highly** recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/). They are JavaScript libraries that will make your life easier when doing [Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) calls and many other JavaScript operations.

Ajax example with jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```